# Troubleshooting double pointers to struct

Tags: c, pointers

I have a struct element and a double pointer to that struct in one of the functions

Struct declaration:

```
struct stackItem
{
    int item;
    struct stackItem *itemBelow;
};
```

Function definition

```
void popItem(struct stackItem **ppTop)

{
    if (*ppTop == NULL)
    {
        printf("The stack is empty, there are no items to pop \n");
    }
    else
    {
        struct stackItem *itemToBeFreed = *ppTop;
        printf("Item that was popped is %d\n", (*ppTop)->item)
        *ppTop = (*ppTop)->itemBelow; // This line fails to compile
        free(itemToBeFreed);
    }

}
```

The compile error i get is:

```
stack.c:109:9: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'struct stackItem **')
        *ppTop = (*ppTop)->itemBelow;
```

Per my understanding , the expressions on either side of the equlas sign evaluate to a pointer to struct stackItem - What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `printf("Item that was popped is %d\n", (*ppTop)->item)` <<--<< add a semicolon, here.

Comment: Jeez, I feel dumb now. I was obsessing over the pointer derefencing, thanks a lot!

Comment: The (confusing) fun thing is that without the `;`, the asterix in `*ppTop = ...`becomes a *binary* operator: see the message: `('int' and 'struct stackItem **)`, where there is still a double pointer.

Comment: @wildplasser Oh, that makes sense. The compiler took it to mean that i was trying to multiply the return value of printf and pptop. Thanks again for all your help!